# SSRS Code is Setting for the next group

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I'm having this issue where my SSRS Report header will show me the value of next group of the report. I am using the Code route to accomplish this. I have two functions, one to set the Value, and one to retrieve it. This is inside the code section of my report.

```
Public Shared varInvoiceNum As Integer

Public Function SetInvoiceNum(InvcNum As Integer) as Integer
varInvoiceNum = InvcNum
End Function

Public Function GetInvoiceNum() as Integer
Return varInvoiceNum
End Function
```

I then have a textbox with an expression that sets the value in the header of the group for Invoice Num. This group only shows Once and cant have it repeating, as it contains address information. In the Report Header is where I call the get function.

The problem occurs when the total section for the report appears on the second page. For whatever the reason, even though the header section in the tablix that contains the Set function call never reappears until the third page. On the Second page the Second Invoice Number will appear. **Even though its still apart of the first group.** It some how gets set to the next value. Any idea how this might be happening?

EDIT: The Second Invoice number in the batch shouldn't be showing, because the Total section is still apart of the First Invoice group. This is the Issue, there is no error message. It just improperly sets the next variable to the next group when the Set Expression hasn't occurred again.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this, what piece of code isn't working? What have you tried? We can't help you if we don't know what's going on.

Comment: I have bolded the Issue in my question. The Second Invoice number in the batch shouldn't be showing, because the Total section is still apart of the First invoice

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the layout, how it should look and how it currently looks. It's difficult to understand exactly what yo mean. Also, you probably won't need your functions to get the correct data if the report design is correct.